# Visual Studio 3D engine

Tags: c#, 3d

I found many questions on StackOverflow but they are either old or not applicable.

I am an experienced developer and I would like to learn for fun and for extending my knowledge some 3D graphics programming.

I am used to Visual Studio and .NET languages and I would like to keep the ease of IntelliSense and the whole IDE as I know it quite well (not necessarly, but a big plus).

Ideally it would be a rapid to start engine, and possibly something widely used not to waste my time and learn something that cannot be useful in a C.V. as well.

I noticed Unity matches partially my criteria (widely used, rapid to start, but not perfectly integrated with Visual Studio). And Xamarin has recently introduced C# in the Unreal Engine (which I understand is quite complex to start and probably not in Visual Studio).

(I need to start from the basics, but I would like to give a try to creating an RPG if there are specific/better engine for this purpose.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Unity, Unreal or cocos2d game engines with VS plugins.

[Visual Studio for Game Development: New Partnerships with Unity, Unreal Engine and Cocos2d](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2015/04/17/visual-studio-for-game-development-new-partnerships-with-unity-unreal-engine-and-cocos2d.aspx)

Microsoft [bought a company SyntaxTree](http://techcrunch.com/2014/07/02/microsoft-acquires-syntaxtree-to-offer-better-unity-support-in-visual-studio/) who worked on UnityVS.

> Unreal offers its own Visual Studio plug-in, and CryTek’s CryEngine pretty much assumes that you are using Visual Studio as your main IDE.

Don't know about Unreal but Unity is pretty easy to learn the basics, there's a tonne of options though.